# How is a static nested class static and if it is then why do we have to use new to initialize it?

Tags: java, static, nested

```
public class MyClass {
public int myclassMember=NestedClass.nestedclassMember; //Compiler error,static reference to a non-static field

    public static class NestedClass {
        public int nestedclassMember=myclassMember; //Compiler error,static reference to a non-static field.
        public NestedClass() {
       }
    }

}
```

But at the same time,the following is totally legal,after removing the compile-time errors of course -:

```
MyClass.NestedClass nestedInstance= new MyClass.NestedClass();
```

What gives?How can the class be both static and non static at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static` doesn't mean the same thing in this context as what it means for fields and methods.

A static nested class is a class that doesn't need any outer class instance to be created.

A non-static nested class needs an instance of its outer class to be created, and has an implicit reference to this instance (available using `TheNameOfTheOuterClass.this` inside the inner class).

Static inner classes are typically used to avoid exposing classes to the outside when they're used only by one class, or to have a class being able to access private fields and methods of an outer class, or to scope a class to another one, because it's tightly linked to it.

Comment: In c# inner class which is not static is indentical(I think) as java inner static class. But inner static class in c# can have only static fields, methods, properties, etc and can not be instantiate. I think utgamer2004 expected that inner classes in java behaves exactly like inner classes in c#

Comment: @icrew yes,that is what i thought,but what i still dont get is why use the keyword static if the class is not static at all,why didnt they just go ahead and create a new keyword like 'Nested'?

Comment: Why in c static global variable or a function means that global variable/function is accessible only in that file? :)

Comment: @utgamer2004 - Adding new keywords to a language risks backward-compatibility issues. Here `static` makes sense in that you call static methods on class `A` and instantiate static class `A.B` both without an instance of `A`. `static` applies to the class itself--not the type of members it is allowed to contain.